# Angular 2 Routing Refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I am trying to Implement Hashlocation Strategy out here it is not working please guide me.

This is My Angular & Router Version

Package.json

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
```

Main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module'; platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list.component';
import { ScheduleListComponent } from './schedules/schedule-list.component';
import { ScheduleEditComponent } from './schedules/schedule-edit.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'users', component: UserListComponent },
{ path: 'schedules', component: ScheduleListComponent },    
{ path: 'schedules/:id/edit', component: ScheduleEditComponent },
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

app.modules.ts

```
import './rxjs-operators';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { LocationStrategy,HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { SlimLoadingBarService, SlimLoadingBarComponent } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DateFormatPipe } from './shared/pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { HighlightDirective } from './shared/directives/highlight.directive';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MobileHideDirective } from './shared/directives/mobile-hide.directive';
import { ScheduleEditComponent } from './schedules/schedule-edit.component';
import { ScheduleListComponent } from './schedules/schedule-list.component';
import { UserCardComponent } from './users/user-card.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

import { DataService } from './shared/services/data.service';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/utils/config.service';
import { ItemsService } from './shared/utils/items.service';
import { MappingService } from './shared/utils/mapping.service';
import { NotificationService } from './shared/utils/notification.service';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DatepickerModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        Ng2BootstrapModule,
        ModalModule,
        ProgressbarModule,
        PaginationModule,
        routing,
        TimepickerModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DateFormatPipe,
        HighlightDirective,
        HomeComponent,
        MobileHideDirective,
        ScheduleEditComponent,
        ScheduleListComponent,
        SlimLoadingBarComponent,
        UserCardComponent,
        UserListComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        DataService,
        ItemsService,
        MappingService,
        NotificationService,
        SlimLoadingBarService,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './rxjs-operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'scheduler',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        // You need this small hack in order to catch application root view container ref
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Scheduler</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css" />

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <scheduler>
        <div class="loader"></div>    
    </scheduler>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <ng2-slim-loading-bar></ng2-slim-loading-bar>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="menuitem" *ngFor="let menuItem of MenuItemss" [value]="menuItem">
                    <a href="{{menuItem.module}}" data-toggle="dropdown" *ngIf="!menuItem.menus">{{menuItem.module}}</a>
                    <a href="{{menuItem.module}}" data-toggle="dropdown" *ngIf="menuItem.menus">{{menuItem.module}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="menuItem.menus">
                        <li *ngFor="let submenu of menuItem.menus" [value]="submenu">
                            <a href="{{submenu.route}}">{{submenu.description}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/schedules']"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/customers']"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/customermaintenance']"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/users']"><i class="fa fa-users fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-info fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-rss-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<br/>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4 class="white">
            <a  target="_blank">chsakell's Blog</a>
            <i>Anything around ASP.NET MVC,Web API, WCF, Entity Framework & Angular</i>
        </h4>
    </div>
</footer>
```

You all know in angular 2 SPA when we refresh we get resource not found or 404 error to avoid i though of implementing the hashlocationstrategy but i am not successfull

kindly share your thoughts and guide me guys.

Thanks for all.

Comment: what is the backend server you are using? NodeJS based, .NET based or anything else?

Comment: Mines is an .Net Project

Comment: how does your base href looks like?

Comment: This is my Base Href  <base href="/">

Comment: so for the first time it loads, what is the URL after you redirect?

Comment: First time I load it goes to app.component.html page  just localhost http://localhost:53318/

Comment: As far as I know, you may not require the `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` line in your module providers. I believe it should work by just passing `{useHash: true}` into the `.forRoot()` function as you're doing now.

Comment: I Tried Different Techniques removed them used only usehash But didn't worked it is the same as usual. I am not seeing hash behavior happening.

Answer (score 0):

**You only need to change on app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list.component';

import { ScheduleListComponent } from './schedules/schedule-list.component';

import { ScheduleEditComponent } from './schedules/schedule-edit.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

{ path: 'users', component: UserListComponent },

{ path: 'schedules', component: ScheduleListComponent },

{ path: 'schedules/:id/edit', component: ScheduleEditComponent },

{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }

];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { 

useHash: true });


**Replace above code with below code** 

import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list.component';

import { ScheduleListComponent } from './schedules/schedule-list.component';

import { ScheduleEditComponent } from './schedules/schedule-edit.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

{ path: '', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'users', component: UserListComponent },

{ path: 'schedules', component: ScheduleListComponent },  

{ path: 'schedules/:id/edit', component: ScheduleEditComponent },

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```