# Angular 2 Components Interaction

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-component-router

I have a custom datagrid which i am trying to interact in my main component.

```
My Custom datagrid.component.ts

import { Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Output, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Host} from '@angular/core';
import { DataGridColumn, DataGridSorter, DataGridButton, DataGridSortInformation, DataGridEventInformation } from './datagrid.core';
import { TransactionalInformation } from '../entities/transactionalinformation.entity';

@Component({
    selector: 'datagrid',
    styleUrls: ['app/shared/datagrid/datagrid.css'],
    inputs: ['rows: rows', 'columns: columns'],
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/datagrid/datagrid.component.html' 
})

@Injectable()
export class DataGrid implements OnInit {

    public columns: Array<DataGridColumn>;
    public rows: Array<any>;
    public sorter: DataGridSorter;
    public pageSizes = [];
    public sortColumn: string;
    public sortDesending: Boolean;
    public sortAscending: Boolean;

    @Output() datagridEvent;

    @Input() pageSize: number;

    public disableFirstPageButton: Boolean;
    public disablePreviousPageButton: Boolean;
    public disableNextPageButton: Boolean;
    public disableLastPageButton: Boolean;
    public pageSizeForGrid: number;

    public currentPageNumber: number;
    public totalRows: number;
    public totalPages: number;
    public itemNumberBegin: number;
    public itemNumberEnd: number;

    constructor() {

        this.sorter = new DataGridSorter();
        this.datagridEvent = new EventEmitter();

        this.disableNextPageButton = false;
        this.disableLastPageButton = false;
        this.disableFirstPageButton = false;
        this.disablePreviousPageButton = false;

        this.disableFirstPageButton = true;
        this.disablePreviousPageButton = true;

        this.pageSizes.push(5);
        this.pageSizes.push(10);
        this.pageSizes.push(15);

        this.pageSizeForGrid = 10;

        this.sortColumn = "";
        this.sortAscending = false;
        this.sortDesending = false;

    }

    public ngOnInit() {}

    public databind(transactionalInformation: TransactionalInformation) {

        this.currentPageNumber = transactionalInformation.currentPageNumber;
        this.totalPages = transactionalInformation.totalPages;
        this.totalRows = transactionalInformation.totalRows;

        this.itemNumberBegin = ((this.currentPageNumber - 1) * this.pageSize) + 1;
        this.itemNumberEnd = this.currentPageNumber * this.pageSize;
        if (this.itemNumberEnd > this.totalRows) {
            this.itemNumberEnd = this.totalRows;
        }

        this.disableNextPageButton = false;
        this.disableLastPageButton = false;
        this.disableFirstPageButton = false;
        this.disablePreviousPageButton = false;

        if (this.currentPageNumber == 1) {
            this.disableFirstPageButton = true;
            this.disablePreviousPageButton = true;
        }

        if (this.currentPageNumber == this.totalPages) {
            this.disableNextPageButton = true;
            this.disableLastPageButton = true;
        }

    }    

    }

}
```

Home.components.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/core';
import { DataGridColumn, DataGridButton, DataGridEventInformation } from '../shared/datagrid/datagrid.core';
import { DataGrid } from '../shared/datagrid/datagrid.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertService } from '../shared/services/alert.service';
import { CustomerService } from '../shared/services/customer.service';
import { AlertBoxComponent } from '../shared/alertbox.component';
import { Customer } from '../shared/entities/customer.entity';
import { TransactionalInformation } from '../shared/entities/transactionalinformation.entity';
import { NotificationService } from '../shared/utils/notification.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    animations: [
        trigger('flyInOut', [
            state('in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({
                    opacity: 0,
                    transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
                }),
                animate('0.6s ease-in')
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate('0.2s 10 ease-out', style({
                    opacity: 0,
                    transform: 'translateX(100%)'
                }))
            ])
        ])
    ]
})  

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(DataGrid) private Grid: DataGrid;

    public title: string = 'Document List';
    public customers: Customer[];
    public columns = [];

    public alerts: Array<string> = [];
    public messageBox: string;

    public totalRows: number;
    public currentPageNumber: number = 1;
    public totalPages: number;
    public pageSize: number;
    public companyName: string;
    public customerCode: string;
    private sortDirection: string;
    private sortExpression: string;

    public autoFilter: Boolean;
    public delaySearch: Boolean;
    public runningSearch: Boolean;

    constructor(private alertService: AlertService,
        private customerService: CustomerService,
        private router: Router,
        private notificationService: NotificationService) {

        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.autoFilter = false;
        this.totalPages = 0;
        this.totalRows = 0;
        this.pageSize = 15;
        this.sortDirection = "ASC";
        this.sortExpression = "CompanyName";
    }

    public ngOnInit() {            
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('customerCode', 'Date Filed', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('companyName', 'PO Name', '[{"width": "9%" , "hyperLink": true, "disableSorting": false}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('city', 'Document', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('zipCode', 'Service Type', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('dateUpdated', 'Case Number', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false, "formatDate": true}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('zipCode', 'Status', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false}]'));
        this.columns.push(new DataGridColumn('dateUpdated', 'Status Date', '[{"width": "9%" , "disableSorting": false, "formatDate": true}]'));
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    private executeSearch(): void {

        if (this.runningSearch == true) return;

        let miliseconds = 500;

        if (this.delaySearch == false) {
            miliseconds = 0;
        }

        this.runningSearch = true;

        setTimeout(() => {

            let customer = new Customer();
            customer.customerCode = this.customerCode;
            customer.companyName = this.companyName;
            customer.pageSize = this.pageSize;
            customer.sortDirection = this.sortDirection;
            customer.sortExpression = this.sortExpression;
            customer.currentPageNumber = this.currentPageNumber;

            this.customerService.getCustomers(customer)
                .subscribe(
                response => this.getCustomersOnSuccess(response),
                response => this.getCustomersOnError(response));

        }, miliseconds)

    }


    private getCustomersOnSuccess(response: Customer): void {

        let transactionalInformation = new TransactionalInformation();
        transactionalInformation.currentPageNumber = this.currentPageNumber;
        transactionalInformation.pageSize = this.pageSize;
        transactionalInformation.totalPages = response.totalPages;
        transactionalInformation.totalRows = response.totalRows;
        transactionalInformation.sortDirection = this.sortDirection;
        transactionalInformation.sortExpression = this.sortExpression;
        this.customers = response.customers;

        this.Grid.databind(transactionalInformation);

        this.alertService.renderSuccessMessage(response.returnMessage);
        this.messageBox = this.alertService.returnFormattedMessage();
        this.alerts = this.alertService.returnAlerts();

        this.runningSearch = false;

    }

    private getCustomersOnError(response): void {

        this.alertService.renderErrorMessage(response.returnMessage);
        this.messageBox = this.alertService.returnFormattedMessage();
        this.alerts = this.alertService.returnAlerts();
        this.runningSearch = false;
    }

    public datagridEvent(event) {
        let datagridEvent: DataGridEventInformation = event.value;

        if (datagridEvent.EventType == "PagingEvent") {
            this.pagingCustomers(datagridEvent.CurrentPageNumber);
        }

        else if (datagridEvent.EventType == "PageSizeChanged") {
            this.pageSizeChanged(datagridEvent.PageSize);
        }

        else if (datagridEvent.EventType == "ItemSelected") {
            this.selectedCustomer(datagridEvent.ItemSelected);
        }

        else if (datagridEvent.EventType == "Sorting") {
            this.sortCustomers(datagridEvent.SortDirection, datagridEvent.SortExpression);
        }
    }


    private selectedCustomer(itemSelected: number) {

        let rowSelected = itemSelected;
        let row = this.customers[rowSelected];
        let id = row.customerID;
        let link = ['/customer', id];
        this.router.navigate(link);
    }

    private sortCustomers(sortDirection: string, sortExpression: string) {
        this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
        this.sortExpression = sortExpression;
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = false;
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    private pagingCustomers(currentPageNumber: number) {
        this.currentPageNumber = currentPageNumber;
        this.delaySearch = false;
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    private pageSizeChanged(pageSize: number) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = false;
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    public reset(): void {
        this.customerCode = "";
        this.companyName = "";
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = false;
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    public search(): void {
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = false;
        this.executeSearch();
    }

    public companyNameChanged(newValue): void {

        if (this.autoFilter == false) return;
        if (newValue == "") return;

        this.companyName = newValue;
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.executeSearch();
        }, 500)

    }

    public customerCodeChanged(newValue): void {

        if (this.autoFilter == false) return;
        if (newValue == "") return;

        this.customerCode = newValue;
        this.currentPageNumber = 1;
        this.delaySearch = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.executeSearch();
        }, 500)

    }

}
```

the issue i am facing here is not able to instantiate that grid object which inherit the datagrid component not able to create a instance out of it to do some operations.

Kindly do the needful and if possible on below these as well

[Angular 2 Routing Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670000/angular-2-routing-refresh)

[Angular 2 Release Version Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735490/angular-2-release-version-component)